# java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%2$s

Tags: android, kotlin

i have string

```
<string name="data">%1$s / %2$s</string>
```

i pass **varargs** in function like that

```
fun getText(varargs text: String) : String {
    return getString(R.string.data,text)
}
```

I called function in the activity

```
getText("1" ,"2")
```

**It gives error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.vivek, PID: 5126
  java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%2$s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2529)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2459)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2911)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer actually does not solve the issue, so I'm not really sure why it's accepted.

It doesn't matter whether you use `String.format`, `Context.getString` or `Fragment.getString` or `Resources.getString`. The problem is in how the `varargs` argument is interpreted. Seems like a Kotlin thing. Simply put, it takes the whole `varargs` as an **array** as if it was a single object and passes that as ***one*** of the `varargs` arguments to the function you call within your function.

So in order to make Kotlin not do that, you just need *spread* the `varargs` argument with an asterisk (the so-called Spread Operator), like so:

```
fun getText(varargs text: String) : String {
    return getString(R.string.data, *text)
}
```

This is a tested solution.

Comment: Saved me a huge headache, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
fun getText(varargs text: String) : String {
    return String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.data), text)
}
```